# Asignación de funciones a threads con for

Tags: python, hilos

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de realizar lo que intento en el código que muestro a continuación, se que de esta forma no funciona pero me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de asignar las funciones a cada hilo de manera "automática" con un for. Gracias

```
import threading

def funcion1():
    for i in range(20):
        print(i)

def funcion2():
    for j in range(20):
        print (j*10)

NUM_HILOS = 2

for x in range(NUM_HILOS):
    hilo=threading.Thread(name='hilo%s' %x, target=funcion%d %x)
    hilo.start()
```

Comment: Tu problema esta en que en `target` quieres añadir una variable a la llamada de una funcion. No puedes hacer eso. Y otra cosa, en `funcion1` te devuelve un `print de 0 a 19 no de 1 a 20`, nose si es lo que quieres que haga, en caso de que quieras que te devuelva prints del 1 al 20 haz `print(i+1)`. Lo mismo con tu funcion dos, deberia ser `print(j+1*10)`

Comment: Si, son funcones de ejemplo sin utilidad real, y se que no puedo añadir variables a la llamada de una función, de ahi mi duda de si lo que "pretendo" hacer con este código es posible de alguna manera.

Comment: De acuerdo, pues bajo mi opinión, creo que no es posible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Python las funciones son objetos como cualquier otro. Por ejemplo, puedes guardar las funciones en una lista

```
funciones = [funcion1, funcion2]
```

y recorrerla en un ciclo `for`

```
for fcn in funciones:
    hilo=threading.Thread(name='hilo %s' % fcn.__name__, target=fcn)
    hilo.start()
```

En cada iteración creamos un `Thread` usando el nombre de la función (`fcn.__name__`) para formar el nombre del thread.

#### Demo

Para la demo no necesito la variable `NUM_HILOS`, ya que la lista de funciones me dice cuantos hilos crear

```
import threading

def funcion1():
    for i in range(20):
        print(i)

def funcion2():
    for j in range(20):
        print (j*10)

funciones = [funcion1, funcion2]
for fcn in funciones:
    hilo=threading.Thread(name='hilo %s' % fcn.__name__, target=fcn)
    hilo.start()
```

produce

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
60
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19

10
20
30
```

...

```
170
180
190

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Por poder puedes hacerlo, aunque no es una buena practica ni algo que se debería hacer.
Te dejo a continuación 3 maneras diferentes de hacerlo.

```py
import threading

def funcion0():
    for i in range(20):
        print(i)

def funcion1():
    for j in range(20):
        print(j * 10)

NUM_HILOS = 2

for x in range(NUM_HILOS):
    # Uso de la funcion locals, devuelve un diccionario con la tabla de símbolos local
    method = locals()[f"funcion{x}"]

    # Uso de la funcion globals, devuelve un diccionario con la tabla de símbolos globales
    method = globals()[f"funcion{x}"]

    # Uso de la funcion eval, parsea el string que le pasas y lo ejecuta
    method = eval(f"funcion{x}")

    hilo = threading.Thread(name=f"hilo{x}", target=method)
    hilo.start()
```

Comment: Si utilizas `globals` ya no hace falta `locals`

Comment: Solo expuse diferentes formas de llegar al resultado.